# component not rendering properly and data.map() is not a function error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, fetch-api

So I'm fetching some data and this data returns an array and I want to map this array, the problem is that the fetch default value is an empty object, I can change the default value of the fetch but that still doesn't work and I can't seem to find an answer that fixes my code.

**EDIT**

Fixed so basically it was how the child was reading the props

This was my code

```jsx
import { useState, useRef, useMemo, createRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import TinderCard from "react-tinder-card";
import { AnimalCard } from "../AnimalCard";
import { useFetch } from "../../../hooks/useFetch";

import "./index.css";

export const AnimalStack = () => {
  const { data: animals } = useFetch("animal-adp/"); // returns {} by default

  const [animals, setAnimals] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(()=> {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
      setAnimals([...data])
    }
  },[])
 // here is some more code that i'm not showing because its irrelevant

 
  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="d-flex justify-content-center w-100"
        style={{ height: "80vh" }}
      >
        {animals.length > 0 ? (
          animals.map((animal, index) => (
            <TinderCard
              className="animal-card"
              ref={childRefs[index]}
              key={animal.id}
              onSwipe={(dir) => swiped(dir, animal.name, index)}
              onCardLeftScreen={() => outOfFrame(animal.name, index)}
            >
              {console.log(animal)}
              <AnimalCard character={animal} />
            </TinderCard>
          ))
        ) : (
          <div>algo</div>
        )}
      </div>
      <div className="m-2 p-1 rounded-2 w-100 d-flex flex-wrap flex-shrink-0 justify-content-center align-items-center gap-2">
        <Button onClick={() => swipe("left")}>Izquierda</Button>
        <Button onClick={() => swipe("right")}>Derecha</Button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

This is my code now

```jsx
import { useState, useRef, useMemo, createRef } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import TinderCard from "react-tinder-card";
import { AnimalCard } from "../AnimalCard";
import { useFetch } from "../../../hooks/useFetch";

import "./index.css";

export const AnimalStack = () => {
  const { loading, error, data: animals } = useFetch("animal-adp/");

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="d-flex justify-content-center w-100"
        style={{ height: "60vh" }}
      >
        {animals?.length > 0 && // this line changed
          animals.map((animal, index) => (
          <TinderCard
            className="animal-card"
            ref={childRefs[index]}
            key={animal.nombre}
            onSwipe={(dir) => swiped(dir, animal.name, index)}
            onCardLeftScreen={() => outOfFrame(animal.name, index)}
          >
            <AnimalCard {...animal} />// this line changed - Here was the erro inside this Animal Card
          </TinderCard>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="m-2 p-1 rounded-2 w-100 d-flex flex-wrap flex-shrink-0 justify-content-center align-items-center gap-2">
        <Button onClick={() => swipe("left")}>Izquierda</Button>
        <Button onClick={() => swipe("right")}>Derecha</Button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: There's the code of my useFetch hook

Comment: I'm not sure you should be re-using `initialState` in your reducer actions. You should probably use `...state` instead. That being said, I don't think it's an issue (yet)

Comment: That still doesn't fix the error. I Found out that it actually does map the array I will edit the code so you can see what I've changed

Comment: Your last edit makes the code invalid. You cannot redeclare the `animals` constant

Comment: `fetch` won't make any difference. Are you sure of the API response format? Is it actually an array of _animal_ objects or is it something else like an object?

Comment: I'm dumb I fixed it, this was never the problem, the problem was AnimalCard, basically I was not getting the props correctly, i was passing it as an all and reading it as a many so it had undefined values of everything.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in your useEffect , you must add dependency in useEffect,like this,
`useEffect(()=> { if (data. length > 0) { setAnimals([...data]) } },[data])`

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't works, thanks for the answer either way

Comment: @MarcoMignacco this would have definitely solved the problem too

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to maintain a copy of the data in the `animals` state; the `useFetch` hook already provides the data as reactive state.

Your issue is that you never update `animals` because your effect hook runs only once on mount when `data` is (probably) undefined.

Simply use the data from your hook. You can even rename it to `animals` if it helps

```jsx
const { loading, error, data: animals } = useFetch("animal-adp/");

if (loading) {
  return <p>Loading...</p>;
}

if (error) {
  return <p className="error">{error}</p>;
}

return (
  <>
    <div
      className="d-flex justify-content-center w-100"
      style={{ height: "80vh" }}
    >
      {animals.map((animal, index) => (
        <TinderCard
          className="animal-card"
          ref={childRefs[index]}
          key={animal.id}
          onSwipe={(dir) => swiped(dir, animal.name, index)}
          onCardLeftScreen={() => outOfFrame(animal.name, index)}
        >
          <AnimalCard character={animal} />
        </TinderCard>
      ))}
    </div>
    <div className="m-2 p-1 rounded-2 w-100 d-flex flex-wrap flex-shrink-0 justify-content-center align-items-center gap-2">
      <Button onClick={() => swipe("left")}>Izquierda</Button>
      <Button onClick={() => swipe("right")}>Derecha</Button>
    </div>
  </>
);
```

[image: Edit bold-frost-7mzqyv]

Comment: I've edited my question so if you can check it out whenever you have time I would really apreciate it

Comment: @MarcoMignacco the edits you made don't change my answer. Does it not work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately It doesn't fix the issue, I can't seem to find why it's not working, thanks for the help

Comment: @MarcoMignacco I've added a CodeSandbox demo and you can clearly see it working